# Windows 10 interrupts GeForce graphics

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, device-manager

My notebook's integrated Intel GPU is working fine on Windows 10. But the dedicated GeForce GT520M is interrpted by the system. (Photo)

I've tryed to update the driver, I've tried to use Display Driver Uninstaller and installing previous versions of the driver. I've tried to make all of these options but without network access (to prevent auto-update). I've tried to keep the power button pressed for 1 minute..

Nothing of the above work. Does anyone have a clue of what is happening? How can i solve this issue and get my graphics working again?

Thanks! =)

[image: GeForce GT520M is interrpted by the system]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
My GeForce is made to work in pair with the Intel Graphics GPU. So the notebook manufacturer (LG in my case) made some modifications in the drivers.

This being said, it's better to get the drivers from the notebook's manufecturer than the originals from nVidia.

I went to my notebook's page at [www.driverscape.com](http://www.driverscape.com) and got the drivers from Intel Graphics and GeForce. Both card drivers should be replaced in order to provide the switchable functionality.

[image: GeForce working fine]